# Why are the columns misaligned when I load a csv file into jupyter notebook (using python and pandas)?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

This is all the code I've written

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import display
df = pd.read_csv("filex56345.csv")

pd.options.display.max_columns = None
df.head()
```

The columns are all there but the values are all bunched up to the right, out of alignment with the titles they should be under.

Everything is fine when I load the file in LibreOffice Calc..

Comment: You'll need to provide a sample of a few lines of the `.csv` file for us to tell you what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Use the parameter `delimeter=";"` in `read_csv`

By default pandas expects it to be `","`

Comment: I have no idea how you can assume this without any example input data.

Comment: When I looked you had posted one.

Comment: Touché. Muito boas